# flash as2: how do i load an external text into a variable? (not loadvars)

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I want to be able to load an external text from an http request to a string in my flash application.

i know that with loadvars i can load variables, when the output is as: key=value&key=value..
but this is not the case here. i get in return a string with several random characters.
how can i properly retrieve them ?

Comment: 1) What kind of text are you trying to load?
2) Is your text file on the same site as your swf file? (Flash is picky about allowing data to be loaded from other domains.)

Comment: the text is on the same site as the swf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by applying toString() on the return object of the onLoad event using an XML object:

```
var x = new XML();
x.load('url');
x.onLoad = function(success) {
if (success)
   var data=this.toString();
}
```

Comment: That's clever... I had been wondering if some PHP could be used to wrap some tags around the content of your text file, but this is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify this a bit to make it work; unfortunately external domains do not work in flash... My solution is this, use it in combination with a php script that imports the data first (put this in the same dir as your .swf). The 'include' command is not supported by many hosting services but there is another php command we can use.

```
if(in_array($url,$allowedurls)){
  $ch = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  $output = curl_exec($ch); 
  curl_close($ch);
```

There is a security risk so use it safely! check this post first: http://christianheilmann.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/

PS: The Actionscript2 code had an error, here is how I corrected it:

```
var x = new XML();
var thedata;
x.load('loadXML.php');
x.onLoad = function(success) {
if (success)
   thedata=this.toString();
}
```